# Is that possible to show huge point cloud with billions of points in Devdept eyeshot control like other point cloud software

Tags: eyeshot

When I tried Fastpointcloud with 1 million points, it is very slow when I zoom or pan. Could you please let me know is there any way to show billion of points in Devdept eyeshot control like other point cloud software ex. AutoCAD?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend splitting the point could into smaller ones. In this way, the one outside the view would not be drawn.

I would also check that the machine has a workstation-class graphics adapter. Integrated GPUs often don't deliver the appropriate performance.